# Appending to one nested list appends to all nested lists

Tags: python, list

example code:

```
my_list = [[]] * 4
my_list[2].append(3)
print my_list
```

expected: `[[], [], [3], []]`

actual: `[[3], [3], [3], [3]]`

My inference is that the nested lists are copies of one another. Is there a way to achieve the `expected`?

Answer (score 0):

Assign `3` a different way

```
l = [[]] * 4
l[2] = [3]
print(l)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 rows.py
> [[], [], [3], []]
> ```

Comment: I don't think that's answering the question. How would you use append specifically? Sometimes the lists are of unknown length.

Comment: His goal was to append 3 to the the l[2] , he was specific.  And he defined his list as 4. Even if the list was an unknown length l[2] is still in it unless it’s a smaller nested list.